# Execute php code only if javascript statement is true

Tags: javascript, php, html

I try to execute php code, depending on how the value of a confirm checkbox was, like in this code snippet.

```
<script>
    var check = confirm ('Are you sure ?');

    if (check == true)
    {
        <?php shell_exec('sudo shutdown -r now'); ?>
    } else {
        <?php 
            header("Location: index.php"); 
            exit();
        ?>
    }

</script>
```

But the confirm dialog box is not showing up, and the shutdown command is executed? Is this even possible?

Comment: of course, it would be impossible the opposite. When JS is executed PHP has already done its work. Look into "sever side" vs "client side" languages

Comment: `php` is executed as user requests for the web page to the server hence it  is **pre-processed hypertext** Whatever you tried here is impossible.

Comment: Best thing you can do is make an ajax call, and execute PHP code if your javascript variable is true..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language, so you can **NOT** execute it from your client side JavaScript. PERIOD. The dialog box is not showing up, because you have some JS errors, an the command is executed because the HTML is rendered on the server, and executes the PHP before sending the whole HTML to the Browser.

AND by the way, you should never do a `shell_exec` based on a confirm dialog like this.

This might be an approach:

**Part of your HTML:**

```
<script>
    function shutDown() {
        if ( confirm ('Are you sure ?') )
        {
            var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhReq.open( "POST", "ajax.php", false );
            xhReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhReq.send("cmd=shutdown");

            var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
            alert(serverResponse); // Shows the return from the PHP script
        } else {
            window.location.href = "index.php";
        }
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:shutDown()"/>shutdown</a>
```

**Part of your PHP file (ajax.php), that handles the AJAX request(s):**

```
if( isset( $_POST["cmd"] ) && $_POST["cmd"] == "shutdown" ) {
    // your shutdown code
    // I'm not sure if "sudo" really works in this context, because you have to verify with a password, except your php process is already running with sudo rights
    shell_exec('sudo shutdown -r now');
}

// you can return something here,
// but it only makes sense if you don't shutdown the server
// you are running the website to shutdown ;)
```

Comment: Why should i never do a `shell_exec` on a confirm dialog? And can you tell me whats wrong with the code? I can't find the error.

Comment: Well, first It won't work, you need AJAX after the confirmation dialog. You can do it, BUT you have to ensure, that the only users who can call this are the one's with the right permission, the server has to be save as hell, because with shel_exec allowed you can have real big problems. If it's just running on your own network, without access from anyone outside, then OK feel free, otherwise you should google for something like shell_exec security, and even if you are doing all to make it save, the problem for example could be some upload directory, where it's possible to create a shellscri ..

Comment: Thx for these helpful informations! I only run it on localhost, so no problem. And every command has to be allowed by me.

Comment: @EdwardBlack: Updated my answer with a code example, but note: this is really just an example, but maybe it'll point you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked fine. You saved me ALOT of time!

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is executed by the browser after it's send to him.
PHP is executed by the server before the answer is analyzed.
Use an XMLHttpRequest to tell you when check is true.

Comment: Are there any practical examples. Links?

Answer (score 2):

You can try **`AJAX`** to send the request to php for executing the shell_exec part, for the redirect part can be managed within jquery you don't need php for that. But again shell_exec is **VERY VERY** **sensitive**, use it with precaution.

in place of `header("Location: index.php");` use `window.location`

in place of `<?php shell_exec('sudo shutdown -r now'); ?>` use `$.ajax({ code here  });`

Comment: +1 for correct answer. -1 for not mentioning that this requires jQuery. Since OP doesn't understand the difference between server/client sides he probably will not understand this.

Comment: I tried `$.ajax({ sudo shutdown -r now });` did not worked.

Comment: Hi Edward 
`$.ajax({ sudo shutdown -r now });` this is wrong the correct way would be 

`$.ajax({ 
      url : "sample.php",
      success: function(response){
          console.log(response);
      });
 });`

Comment: Then in your **sample.php** place the code `shell_exec('sudo shutdown -r now'); echo json_encode(array('response'=>true));`

Answer (score -7):

This should work as long as the page is save as *.php

```
<script>

    if (confirm ('Are you sure ?'))
    {
        <?php shell_exec('sudo shutdown -r now'); ?>
    } else {
        <?php 
            header("Location: index.php"); 
            exit();
        ?>
    }

</script>
```

Comment: No, doesn't work either. The confirm box is not showing up.